# jqgrid Tooltip on page buttons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I noticed that when you hover the mouse over the reload and search buttons at the bottom of the grid, a tooltip appears indicating "reload" and "search" .. I'd like the same behaviour with the next page buttons (the left,right arrows) , last page button. Any idea how i can accomplish that without modifying any source code? I noticed that there is no title attribute on those buttons, thats why there's no tooltip. 
Any tips would be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the title attribute dynamically in the gridComplete event:

```
jqGrid({ gridComplete: function() { 
      $("#pager").find("the_button_selector").attr("title", "Button tooltip"); 
   }, 
   ... 
});
```

You'll have to find out those button's ids and use them instead of "the_button_selector". Should be easy with FireBug, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So i am guessing there isn't any inbuilt feature in the grid where we can define this.

Comment: Nothing I know about. I'm not expert, of course, but last week I spent reading lots of jqGrid wiki pages ;-) But it's _very_ easy to setup, for example $("#pager td#first span").attr("title", "Go to first record"); and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If u want to add tooltip on your custom jqgrid buttons then just add title.

```
.navButtonAdd('#discPgr',{ title:"Add Discount"});
```